# Python add column values from one dataframe to column in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, addition

I have two dataframes. I want add column values from one dataframe to another, without changing other columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dff1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[20160501,20160501,20160501,20160501,20160502,20160502],
                     'Time':['0900','0905','0910','0915','0920','0925'],
                 'SKU':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                 'Demand':[10,35,20,15,5,55],
                 'Supply':[10,20,15,20,0,45]}
                ,columns=['Date', 'Time','SKU', 'Demand', 'Supply'])
dff1 = dff1.set_index(['Date', 'Time']);
dff2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[20160501,20160501,20160501,20160501,20160502,20160502,20160503],
                     'Time':['0900','0902','0910','0915','0920','0925','0900'],
                 'SKU':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                 'Demand':[10,35,20,15,5,55,60],
                 'Supply':[10,20,15,20,0,45,50]}
                ,columns=['Date', 'Time','SKU', 'Demand', 'Supply'])
dff2 = dff2.set_index(['Date', 'Time']);
dff3 = dff1.add(dff2, fill_value=0)
dff3.reset_index()
```

The first dataframe have **Date**: 20160501 and **Time**: 0905, second dataframe does not have this Time for the Date, but have **Date**:20160501 and **Time**: 0902. So the challenge is to add missing Date/Time records from one dataframe to another, sum values in **SKU** column if there is a record already. Without changing other columns.

First:

```
                    SKU Demand  Supply
Date        Time            
20160501    0900    1   10  10
            0905    2   35  20
            0910    3   20  15
            0915    4   15  20
20160502    0920    5   5   0
            0925    6   55  45
```

Second:

```
                    SKU Demand  Supply
Date        Time            
20160501    0900    1   10  10
            0902    2   35  20
            0910    3   20  15
            0915    4   15  20
20160502    0920    5   5   0
            0925    6   55  45
20160503    0900    7   60  50
```

Desired output:

```
                    SKU Demand  Supply
Date        Time            
20160501    0900    2.0  10.0   10.0
            0902    2.0  35.0   20.0
            0905    2.0  35.0   20.0
            0910    6.0  20.0   15.0
            0915    8.0  15.0   20.0
20160502    0920    10.0 5.0    0.0
            0925    12.0 55.0   45.0
20160503    0900    7.0  60.0   50.0
```

My output:

```
                    SKU Demand  Supply
Date        Time            
20160501    0900    2.0  20.0   20.0
            0902    2.0  35.0   20.0
            0905    2.0  35.0   20.0
            0910    6.0  40.0   30.0
            0915    8.0  30.0   40.0
20160502    0920    10.0 10.0   0.0
            0925    12.0 110.0  90.0
20160503    0900    7.0  60.0   50.0
```

Issue: Demand and Supply columns also summed.

Update:
I achieved the desired result after a sleepless night:

```
dff31 = pd.merge(dff1, dff2, how='outer', on=['Date', 'Time'])
dff31.fillna(-1,inplace=True)
dff31['SKU']=dff31['SKU_x']+dff31['SKU_y']
dff31['Demand']=dff31['Demand_x']
dff31['Supply']=dff31['Supply_x']
#dff['Supply']=dff['Supply_x']
for x in range(len(dff31['Demand_x'])):
    a = dff31['Demand_x'][x]
    b = dff31['Demand_y'][x]
    if (a > 0):
        dff31['Demand'][x]=a
    else:
        dff31['Demand'][x]=b

    c = dff31['Supply_x'][x]
    d = dff31['Supply_y'][x]
    if (c > 0):
        dff31['Supply'][x]=a
    else:
        dff31['Supply'][x]=b
dff31 = dff31.drop(columns=['SKU_x','Demand_x','Supply_x','SKU_y','Demand_y','Supply_y'])
```

But I believe that this is not actually "pythonic" way. Still hope someone can help me!